# How to know if user disconnected from my Stripe Connect app?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I can provide a disconnect option on my app, as described here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started#revoked-access

But if a user revokes access to my app through his account settings, how can I know about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to setup a [webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) endpoint URL for your connect app where you listen for the event `account.application.deauthorized` to detect that the user has disconnected your application.

When you go and try to retrieve the event to ensure it's valid with the [Retrieve Event API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_event) you will get an error because your application is not authorized anymore:

> Stripe::AuthenticationError: (Status 401) Expired API key provided: sk_********.  Application access may have been revoked.

You can rely on the fact that you get a `401` status code in that case to ensure that the event is valid otherwise you would get a different error

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip about the expired api key message. I was really stumped on how to verify this webhook.